# From fabric first-network example, why set up organization?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

From [fabric First Network example](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#id1) , why set up organization? what is orga use for?

Answer (score 2):

In Hyperledger Fabric, every participant (client, peer, orderer) belongs to some organization.

Organizations have certificate authorities that provide their members (clients, peers, orderers) enrollment certificates in order to authenticate one another, and other organizations.

It also provides an easy way to aggregate participants together in order to define access control rules that span multiple clients, peers and orderers without having to define for each participant separately

Comment: Do  organizations have certificates ?And every participant (client, peer, orderer)  have vertificates too?How  does organizations control their participants?

Comment: Every organization has a root CA or an intermediate CA.
Therefore - each has its own certificate.

It's the CA's role to create certificates for its associated network members (clients, peers, ordererers).
An organization can also revoke its member via issuing a CRL and sending it to every channel the organization participates in as a configuration update for that channel.